# How to set blob url in image source

Tags: html, angular, image, file, blob

I get a binary file back from the server and would like to show it in the frontend. I convert my binary file to a blob and use the DOM Sanitizer to create a save URL.

The problem is that the image is not found when I used the blob URL for the image source:

[image: Blob URL]

**Typescript:**

```js
const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

const fileData = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

**HTML:**

```html
   <img [src]="fileData">
```

**Response from Server**

```
�PNG


IHDR��91tHiCCPICC ProfileH��WXS��[RIh�H ��R�K   �E�*�I �ĘD�ʢ�k���"��;��(v��P��u�`C�M
����������ϙs�S2��t�yRi.�@�$_����"u`���ǗK�qq���������r�E����=�P���8C ��A|��/��@�z�i�R%���&�T��ԸX�3ԸBe�ρxd�'�@�   �Y�,ȣ}bW�@,@�q _�@  )J�C�7<Y����������C�ri.o��َ�-y���vp�D��xeͰowr�D)1
�nIFL,���T��T�"2Im�����3���U�����pInL�F��)�BWZ(��&j|    �a  �jٔ���)�5��<�*����"'���#r���S�9c�qr��3�9    Qj̦Hĉ��)���@�'�D����I���x��,O>P/�H$��hpe�(1Ró��S�oq�P�N���E�"���kǮ
%I�z�vi~H����47Nc�S��J�Ħ��/�������%���3�y����� p@(``
�����n�K=x@���h4)�  �&�"�DB �Q�
A�Ԫ�. S5[���O �Q �V��$�ђ�P#�!:��r�Gj�5�/Kg��F%FÉ��  ������;��d�՞��FxL�Ih'ܝ,�/���a�pM��֌�AVO<���g�&� #�� �j9�̕������Ǝ�JA)C(���=���=Y�=��C�\3����>>�N�=�{Kl�;���.`G�F�cM�e���?T�h Z�*��#�!OS�I�k�k��'�\��P�~�)��2q�(�ņo~!�+��rwu�@�Q��^3U��y�n�������j`��_u�����$��
Y�Z�+/@:�2��8�z܁�� �� ��I��"��e`�   �P��5�l[�����8  ΂K�*�   ����    ����!BB�1F,[�qG|�@$�F�T$�B$���,@ʐ�H%��E~E!'�Hry�t!���(��P��CG�>(�Bщh:-B�ѥhZ��BГ�%�&ڎ>G{1�iaL�s�|0��a�����b�X
V�5���:֎ucp"��Y�\��x�ǧ��%x%�o�O���Gx��@'��  ~.a!�0�PB('l#$��OS'�-�Hd���iL%fg���Oۈ�^�dLr&�bI<R>������t�t��IzO�"[�����4��<�\N�I>F�F~J��Rl)~�X��2������L�B��Q����j"5�:�ZA����ާ���Ҳ����%֚�U��W��#�4}��C�@SЖҶ�N���^��t;z0=��O_J����?���fh��j��hWi7h_�~�Cѱ�a�L�)�)�ٯsE�[��k������֭�=�{[�W�������Do���g�$};�0}�~���S��a��0�����3�N���� ۠�`�A�A����H�d�B�*ã��L�i��2s�˘������
aY<�~ȵ!    �J���4�h�23�1^a�h��7q2k2�d����C����7�wS���4�t���˦�f�ffR�uf�̺͙�����͏�wY0,-��-�[��2d�Y��
�iV���e���r�e�e���U��|�=V���>֙֫�[�{l,l��̴���ݖb�c+�]k{�����]��B�F�g�F�\�"�:��t� ��57��>�9���:�N�N"�*�+Ψ����y�s�0�0�a�a5�n��\�..u.��3�G�?�q��6#�F�qn�WO�\׭�����F��wkv{����w�r��A�������r��H��
#�x2<�x.�l�����%�����N�����c����/�7�w���~^~�~����w������l��(ᨭ�:�x��Y�遛ۃ,�xA5A�����ۂ�����]�!�!���!�8~�Y��XhDhihk�~XRXe��p����ψ'" �Q�+"os͸|n-�g���Y�OGѢ�*�G;Eˢ�ǠcF�Y5�~�m�$�1�rcW�>����wx,ql�ت�O���gƟK`$LNؙ�61$qY�$�$ERK�N����w)�)+S�Ǎ7kܥT�TqjS)-9m[Z����k�wN�P2��D���/L2��;��d�ɼ���  �)�;�?�by5��nFuF��_�.�t �+�O32Wf>�
�Z��%
����q��evd���w9�9�s�sSr�����I�%9��ŞNi�:KK��S�����#��m�#��|�a��pP��xTXPU�~Z���z����ӝ�/���(��������3��|4�=k�ldv��9�s��t΍��cu^μ���_9�͂���f�s�;~����D�DVr{����E�E��=�[��TPz�̵�������?��\�s��̥�˼�mXN\.Y~kEЊ+�V��X5fU�j����o�L^s�|d�ƵԵ����M�l�-_��RTy�*�jO�i���w��m�P��lc�Ə�ě�l���PcWS����`˓��[����K�6�me�>o�lo���t�wm�Nӝ���:E]׮ �����T�R�ysO�^�W���_���/j_�~���lTd,m@�7�4�ۛR���>����|����ۏX�:jxt�1��c�ǋ������>�u��er˽S�N�8=�t뙨3�φ�=u�}�����G.�]8t��b�%�K
�=/��^�
W��4]����6��ص�k'��^?{�{��͘�m��nݹ=�v���gws������{s��>�}P���aͿ���ݫ���G�'<����x����O��O�OʟZ<�}���HWx��?����\�����/���_8�8�w�ߗ{��t���������oF�i��}�6�m߻����w|��p�c�ǧ}�>�>U|v���%������~)O�Sm08��L^m��
�*�?�W��T��Ϧ*�V�U�@=�)����.rûr��P���y�����O<������ ���gY�����[a�w81U}�T
�
6+�M#�\������ꯈ  pHYs%%IR$��iTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 5.4.0">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:exif="http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/">
         <exif:PixelXDimension>202</exif:PixelXDimension>
         <exif:PixelYDimension>188</exif:PixelYDimension>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
M�uiDOT^(^^lKgf8IDATx�  �U����l6��  PFPA�)H8b@
CD��J��$�U
TT.��*ZKQ�*<�P,�(��-9� ��9�=fwf��?���9z�gwf���ߵ;����~�������=3��=��M5�h�OAi��T
�5�@
((  ��"�Em@5�@
J%��j@AQP
$Ѐ��@I*�PP�T    4��$P�����@
((  ��"�Em@5�@
J%��j@AQP
$Ѐ��@I*�PP�T    4��$P�����@
((  ��"�Em@5�@
J%��j@AQP
$Ѐ��@I*�PP�T    4��$P�����@
((  ��"�Em@5�@
J%��j@AQP
$Ѐ��@I.�T:�����Y�;űk�*�FPZ#BQPf�����5{�?��&i����ԛP�J|�{|x
<o;�wc~�2��g��/�c��z1��J����7�����J�%P�����whWQ<�   �����mC�
=����ޮ6�vU�,�R�`��m�?����N�"�4�ۡQP�`X��1�����F��S�m�M+0��#�+q$����;�    �bC���#���%��R���9��x��H�f�����@hV�xe5T*}�ހ��&�t��QP�Qê^�~��?�逸��fX������͡5��q-5�UYM�����t0
J�E�gz�a���E��t}e�J���!_>��c&�%�8
�I30
J��������H���\y+��O�,8>�2S��.FA �E41��~��?55ݕ-�a�a>��يO,���YʁQP��d�8I��Y[[4�t����X�t�W�_p"1(�a"F�c�I)0

^u
���;0��Izh�mJe`�t&z�uà��C(˩RX��4M�g5(��
�y?qv���;��{1��O@�Lw�i���L���"ί
j��!0)�.��^�O�En�K;[�HĶ��ȕΆB�ĠԚ~�
xh�m5�M+0��>�6��Lt�gu}A-�ktPm�k

y��&U|��lX
�\ZN�U�����-j=��*iQ���Y�tA�D?J���A�35^�0(�]\�eր҃+��7���Sk�o��2,�����F��(#�E�)(z�f��m���3+@������&�Ui`����o4��q:���)L�A�6ԥ�ޥ�A��=����U�H3������P���W1��w�U
�-�82o�jPde�r��-)�++b�[q��  RguG�Dd�-&��.���e&&�]�z1�N���΃B�=�5�xŬb5�2�Q��V.%�#�.m�2�.�
KW��s�Z#l~�x1�KG���f�<��� ��PA $/#�,]
�ne��o�c��������a�(Bk��}POE�K���#�0�(��0��@��$�3ףbu ���:�����`�r|�a1{�(0C���?L�.����p}(�YnN�#wmz�]���ɮ%�_�7�o#M{//���ϣ�`@�X#`��/�ȹ%��Ȼ��Lz��EKij��+��7%�1��"�7F��J������`�r$Q��כ�y7S�t(�l�iw�l���0�>ڻ�v�
Y�wA\��F+c\1c��zT~��Hi�D
����5�UI�}�d�a8f���?;w�I�Ep5�l{j�R��KӇ+��J=(Y��y���A[z�ϳ.e���Zl�w��N�(o�k�$w<K�A�O&��4��#�����O B���Q�BuA(��
��G`I-(�����Z
�a��B���^�
��л(�HD�-��d�&�a�����0�E�J�ɠl2�Ԃ��m�u_1�<m�J�a�p!{��N��f�Q(�.%0��"�N]���R(��4���:��7
��bi2"�.xp$e�A0؛�k��5en�",uφE<K;`I%(Y�z��w��nû���q�
�7�9b�?
�&4db��b8��QO��%u��78�'us_C�Oὕ�l��F�
�K� ����feRX�~�a�ȍ��&N�������kN_��  ���ؕ
GY�B��2v!tb��_��}LJ@U����@f�$�'�f
(��ٌ~�ט@*v����P<
��)a�����a��K+�ԣ"Db7�%U%�߈s�t�|*����/-���e�I@D"Xd�ቴ
`@��E�Dds힯��}�����h2-�I}��,X�q�ISHD���>�    �$�����Da�ez�]����kK���y���3p�'=/�sH���ʹ��0�T�B�f#F8I�xX��ʶ�mE��K*@�����\�oAz>4�4�2�3w3���M�+����A&����xnd
�0�O(�ޟ��@���P�l3_H��G7"�,&o'�Tǡ�KЋ`&�\507$�+a���`�E�f�J�K��v\*�D �g2)XZ��&���{�A�����|n����4h`g���=�X�A��.��Cf)LG�O��
}�+�R�ۆ��Q�Ɵ�ں���h�s�RX<H�Wq
��B@)b"4p6��J�<�HRڈg�
��D���9TТQ�yP��&�w�H����lt�{�`���}�,�%K�������/�����TW���л>A#�o�8�`]t��N�pH����Q��T����g6�i�F�:u�^��ևv��.���7�@����2�x�����>Xv�x����S���{㚤��V�v�|++�a�p�M6M�A�Y�s.l��5��#��4��&+�4��O8
J�d̦�&�+��~���������k�ŒLƃ�]��?>��@8|y�=�!�'����`0���؛�^�C2r4Ƣ�^�}�+�Q�=����Wq�^�.��E���l���U���g����R�ݫͧ�v�~p�+��w���;��P��N5^����M6̮�E��!�+Y�$I��C0�n��L�]�*9=��4(i��<�� \z��p��rA��l�̏,�k�Y4�8�C�G�2��H<�Xr���3�Л`Q`�!xjoD�X��������&�73+W�w��e�{��G�PI.W����/��-۠X�\�ico�.<�|�
�f3�x��U��;G��GuY@0e���mY�D�&�v��*�3+�X���YP|���ԏء��;�p������ۉQ�z���k`�^n��m�&��D�ɭ��Xgk9@��&L�2�� -�<r�#�ySK�U���o�f�0|���G�uvb���_��f'�`{r���5��~1oҲ�WJp��R��m�L(TCB�X�
Kg���7_xq�]{/��]��R����s-�ei֥ac�Fx�1b���]��8��ɋC!���0�`b/my�b��m|�z�bA���Y�2׿�zw�#u$U(��u[�����#}��a�Ha=>v���!��O�ܵ��xb/��{D������?�[�LW�n|6m���p��㬏.��o�/wpl+���yaK��Ũ�ws���B>�z�˔����p��.7^w�V��e~�k���O�   9�Jw�מ�ő�$Ɲ8�_�n�d��$U����]"��)�0Q�i{3iXl%�l"+Pծ�I&���P[���Sq���m+/�����9[ᗿ~ɍ�$ű�����7����®��e�
�Bll�E���X!{*��@ĥ��-�����D �ꗳ�����w�/�/�W���w��%l��/����ާ��N�?z�~�0��&Yuİ��8���L�\���<��M�z<v\��0(�0���Ð_��I��4nW^q\��#�:=����D������z,a��� �t  .�5.Z
���l��:�?[��I�/'A�xs���⟰��;]�4�]V7'�/l��I6��>�
m2�`K
�%C�$�U��E�����7s��RB�z^B���Ps�#I��0(�����8���x����!,}s�}��v�ūC����x�0�6r6_�a��,�q�%f���N��Fq�T�����&w��%�IDAT�}    ���Y׹˷$���Ӥ�EҔ��@�`-�
��a�ڢ-E
�M�AQ�Zk��"%"Gg��8�ǥ$��N˴j馃4��/߾^��s��r��~�{����s�g;�y��{������<q��FYـG7��^�ǵg?�?���΍,R��s��Zy汿���U�z���0S��J)|q����B�
    n�[٠�^)P�(ͲBKYJ���OR�tO���q�:/��������w�_��勏��/�u���'���v���#��lQ����uI���De~ #��{%~�d��@lV�i%�E���y�"�3��Px��ܴ��X�IFP�k*����#�d�.��C�ӟx����ƅ��屣�AvG�j$p��
d��t$�
�H�?1����'�#T�f�d05��孈�a�:�r��>^~��0
_���k_s{����붫v��/l<�<z��/O^�Y���m�B���_֑����5"(�������y2�3N�f�����?(k+�E�����P�������m��w}u����m�])�s�[?�#���:����7y��:A�
\IOi_+ے�ԉB����h���QAS��况�*�+�k�GP?u�Ly�]�q�kk+�3�����_?�(څ��_R�8��$�Q��g'{�<u�d@0�uDLz�#AǱ��PV0�~OC_�(��1Dr�#P����,�V~CΎ����Ty�]��;��]���˿��^-��g�.O�|��cr�ֈI�l�@Q�&�ˤeG��J��=O~%�19��V�g�~U�cʁ�_)V�s]�:;�Tٿ�|�ï*_���������;�-;ב���9    L`�ք�8��ʷ"�mN�U�Fy��͘l�%乘�k��+�w�FT���~���rD�w�i��-/�/p�8O������W��
f-�9�%0 |j`K~d8q sb@����s�O-����BC�gT�=P�V>S��2�������oz����}�euU�4�0>y��̹/�>1}���ԮK�(���j~�h:̓�Q���۞c��g�z�?j����妵�:FV_��Q����Q�ӯ���<�;����/����e߾�Q����w��7"m]�����b��Q�AY!�z�I@(?x���C�Ӥ�j��(hC����C�o/�+O�ٱU'O�/��������F���������l�'  u~�|��y(vL�|���K
�d0K���k@ʹ+������sK��z�`%u2<�TvPtu(底��}��i�GX�dy��|�����T9{��5����������܏�8}�e�o��D�*ә��g��
DFZP/��e��  '�B�A�+�B)"����W}F  ��_�`9��o�옫����7}�|�sG���_��g>���/<�̿�I�9}o9~���$L�<    <6 ����%��:zh���j���x'(����/�V>����zG^?���/N&د���{����~���|�ho�&��ı����rl4F���t��Np���2�*F�(qc���zJ�ʰ��"��ؗY�<Qz�p
7��-�b<_��q�����^y��}t�ze�/|�
����r���Y���R6���ȑZ����<�M��dF:
(::�%Pj �cN�$}�7?|���5�?}�-���7����?qSN���Sx>9|�'��-�R��S�K5hrh�X�[ʅ0{:����o��r�����֟����ݯ�o{�����n.G����g�3�}}���G�۞s��z���[ݿ�E�ʫ<������S����+����R�B�l(z��p
0&�v����3�����u��L�ߪ<���V��
y?>�x��>{�k�R�=��O�7m�k=F�~��@�!b�'��'�S,��O�9�����|F�[tׯ�o�J��%�}��>_��w?���7����w|e������w���s_^�<�Α�'�(�ޥ�[wM�@ٿ��(o�>��c����-?C��������5���p[[�����������@�䭟���S�i��A����>��N�yͯm��>�|���/���nxƸ�
�(k��gލۮK�\l{�y@���k��ߧ<܋_�������?�?
?;�U^|�寽���_���m8M�z9y������0lv���x���͙�᭟Q�aFM�Xe�<����V?��~��!��_Yy�;�?�:t�z��{�W�������{�A}�My��������?�Jr(�7�9�&@��A�}���(���a�G��������7��X���}嫿ꏔ�}ճ����B�,�0g�_<����-��)�I�$�@iǍ���!Sh{�s�(�+X�Y�o��>��r�̟���@!l��WT<v�'O�MEXE��?��]+�`��r�ڏ���W�e5��=�����WOz�����t����G��:!܆����d����a%�b.)��#��̟� �c��00    �}+������e=��H�8�5��LI�fv�4)Ne+V5)�qҔz1H=�P��3��6iA��w��k'�W�XW
��EZo8~��[֣���s/*O���;6(��A�2q�P���x>�1L    C�*�>�PHz��%0B��;6��*�2�Q�K��<Q�e�bP���>�7��,#��S'�+����P��!P�&&�́Lx/���p�`LJ>��ɟ;8@vwEJ�u���q�ݯ�m��'��]��z�$�I�Hw��)��[�DDW@   ���D0�% .�e��   ش�'��u���3Jw���P��q��w<����O�?���m��L�əѩ�v�\�C��+�Ӄy,Q(��^U6(�����|!R�4*�Щ�>�ו"������_��Ֆe$8r�[�����#F  ^�3����CI�ת
�z
����,I��a��g(�K �Y'J���P
2��
k��,��A]6�2|&y��}J�!H���DB��ۮ�S��L`e<��$�b��I@Lzk� �y�
�U�����;���'G[�����/�����ct�U�-���-��ra&kzV;"�m����@�O3T�"B2J��w�B9��1
�)ٱ^%%��FnQ%o���Q�(tt�
���(�l(�>|
���_J�x���p��J�v��3����J[&}�"�3�Hj  ��"�P0$=!�d�--?S�Vd���Fg�e���/c����D�A���Q�:��,W?����r��wդ�V�lr�p���rY�ZO�!'*�m�喜�)�%(Y�P�A>sv0���z3,;(��l�C��7U�Djg�Ru����co��<    ��ng�|�u��:0xT��a��tܢ $�JP�KA�0PqL_�_������[}�<z��y���6�,Z2�\LK�++�,���49�r�#p�����z+8��{��*�̈́_J[�M~�W�^����4k?�ˎ��tH���s�3�ţY@I�݉B���Ww
�#�Yr|��@��ϔC�~�f��F` ��r����{*C�0����&h��\�E��A��Bڷ�J�*Giٞ:Mh�R�IR�'�5���^t�@���E/ы�e��D����Gq��\H,�+�����'Ͼ�&����&ejG]ؘ�u0���A�(&��Df��a����c���,��f��:ML[�.
֡#���v�ٿ��rþ_l+]�.[�>��r�̟��L�!P��(�C�JKO��^I�٧ �L��0�Mj7�P���l�ӃЇ-�R_ţ�AW-�K��4(!��
K��w7��7�7���������g�Oq�    P3�v䀒�٧ ��L_1�~�佌�)U&N[�O��C�TJ+����c{{8C��Ǡ��SB�j=ppU15_�D���������e{  ��$�q�EM2�IՊ��Q�/�$���O�[�L}�4T�lY�NE�iKI.�9)M�L5g�8��s����Hx}X!�
    ż��_�N��O����W�WT�W�$��$�$N���D��PdbS5�H��*a��%)�"��AȠ�W���{�Q�NSZ�i��8���Eo�,�+��-����;c���n������c�k�·��x��ݢN&��k$�e��&0�� M$5
�h���DY/`$��r݀�Y*���˼e��+�F�IF+ѐ��o�5)�Q>̧s\<����υp�R; 1@���ֱ�V7+�����������$�0����|NBqEs���
��;! �K���v�|����GG")c�d-A�!(����J����[$���%e��N�~�X.�"(Z��T1Lo�_��k�p�Έ@~-��>q.$J`ڊ��mf��
Hp�
�MD)ms�5}D?N�@��1x9�9�.z�%ٱ>�{AĤ�V�������c����A��:��W�,�u��D�o9����s�0�U��D�7�}/!`�п�Ž�xO-m��|��%x?��o  Kc(��3Q�<٧��    N�\E aX��D���CS`�V������B䕂�`H��������߳DL�{�#'����p� a���vAB=e�$ܩ�]v2QEy�۩`KH��H�(<�I&��7    �b=]vP�����\t�()���v�����c���y��y�����Su�Y d�&'I�&��Y�Շ�\�.���V�
P�Z�c5���>��Κe������U@׳����(lq�0���PJ���$����N�g
�ı�I��VjP&O2'e���ٴ��5m�U��Q[�:"F-�{7�l�>�i���Q�~ەϼ͗�f�F��Q'5��ŧ�瀑heީ�%-��0�X�k��o�t� n�>�����ֱ3ߨ?)�˫Q�qM�i���;���� �L%!'�����L��@�$Vp�
�̡��0����6�O���&���<�d��c(\x�]��$t9d6v\�$ʅ�Z�F�p�\�[���ߓ�n��gNy�u����O�k�L� G�I��$�
)�a���6A�9��<�i mR��S�5��ӄ�\aNC�ʎ8Q�r�E�*���h��Řa��X(��7����K��S����3�~�^���Y+�)�4H,::��Lj�(�]�J�
�5O�0�#��F���͉�hh�#�c�1�&�6�Z
s�*wP�4]E�.�Z(�����/����S�!b�S�c���J�^��C�k�)�@��|�:u�����������UY �$��bF�oW��O�,˾�����z2P���7�A�=�:5)0!4W7�f�������<�ͩv̉B�3��XE«����0 �C���A�A)�����gq��NF.}
��(>���p9�Ǆd�a�Sg�N��㟃��)��kˊ�,�_�d0Ť�q�LfȪ�i�-Am�JP`�3�~�(���/ ~�O��
��$t��4M�(�R�e���R��^#I^p�A�P�
!��`���U�ڷn��[�0���4�������Әe�?U�+Z6�A=��>w�-��8n�b>����vz��B9�g)��-z
��2?�c��w�m�N��!8�{4ͭ�0�cϯ��r7AAW���ʎ:Q��LdmP��v�H�.]�%_="P�.qRخ$9��H�tmN��F<ʾ�/�����o"���������Sɺ����[�9<��>�����;���w�~�d8]&f�ek�І"��8y57�h�9"i�S�c63A�o ��'?O/���#���F�r�����`�
9
,Ô�-�5(F�I��d�A�n�t�����$�6����L�<����em�Q�扲���������:�|�Y�i��h��47�S���-���/�g� ��w�\�bp��0��JA�H2�[
��g�0��L5�x���}�K/�bx�5$t��_d�U���G,�?�Kՙ��q'
��y:    ������T�����Ր�B��[�����P�`�T��$�s�0�H��agf�8�ᒔo�Z3���i=�P�Ey��y,f���(����0<��`&��b ����-��I���4g��#��<Aw蟸s� �&sp
,��J��'{����f�vj
P1�.��zN��^qC1������rH])jC�������~�|�@0,�����DDʅ1�$���}u'S�*C��ŞQϼ����E'�r�DpE��^�%_Q����   �wP ��W;���W��0x��m2�S[,T���LA�I1���`M[�j��+Si.Έ���n��������zu똲�">��*�� �&�h���.�T-rR���M���*3ɋ�;(\��S�����Nl�H����E:��v(i+p�Ĝ��QER��6���c�eҭF���l��Tu=�FV5Q�S�"5��&m)�8��.�@|���F�m��  %X�ן$�J�r��Tc���7���t��� �՝�0O�Y�x� v.�cy=!���b��WE�2��{6*X����L�E?Aa8W��
���*g��,��$�&�b�5����M%҇�ʯ�J2
 �4�4%�j�D���S�d$�� �
z<$`�xb��F�w�(�=�?�f,
J��:�$��+��������!iE�z��l��v�˴�i��+zcr5?�4ME了�SȉQ�%<o�hR�x�XCQB��s0�ɪ9--Dt[��^���y��~���@�8��Z��Gal[9�[���!��5tC$Y��;��+9�d�,   Gn1�09"C��
��&�!&K��OA$�3W][M�`V�ce�;��[7����4������Q��X&J>4�![�vRwR��;�ɯ�}20$dH��w�A�E�*�hA�ɮluƀ[#��(͹Y�c��U���@��ʚ����ԣ��4�}7�2Q("QU$�p踫1���p`�m՜/���q�=���/�)�X"�x�Aې��g�����|�HGv
�ܛ��m4y����������
�9��b�Z��>X���U6T�
,N�6��"����ܲ�٦��}���=iǒ���/UTr.�n{�n�=y�0u*a?�i�����$3@d�U��)B�L�N�T�ס�����'2�  �lB�ꊏ:�,�� d��,m
�]��p勁%�ޱ�hA�XV3�F,�
���n��0]0Vl��4McE�����j�/-�2�D�~�\���wI? ��"�ӊl�$�%�Is�z�� H8ݮ
Ԓi�݉�+3K�v�hS�@���4��|G�p!G��)��d1wM��3��u$-�H�^;MuӞ�(6�A��04i:��I���}���y��E��0�y92ӎ�0QtK��J�N�Eck����<�T���ٵ@q�����y���`�i,NtX8����"V��j�Y�   ,ؖ�)*RRϕ�f?/ɔ����1�X_�w�涚k��o��W�b��W��m`   PFB������~�\�Y��Х�"A"�9m:s��
㐉�������D�(|
Nn�����fbknx�E
'Ҷ��P
��l�P�",0Z>�)T��1hr�Ux�m�E�,�B;ZB0-�9�����m�=X��6cF��^�[#5�"%�D��el�Z]��,Վqi�]  ��r��[H�x1  ����6�t<�CxL�6%�d�4 ��"%4��L��iʀ=wP�JB� �b�d�,��˥�r�������x�$@�m��+:��Xt8TdG��k���]:X��4�I��@������S�[�Q�r�B+S�� _&�X���(J��$���(]W{�� |!+l�T���.��Kd���*W)��%XTbq:S��k�Ib���N�
K.b�����M�+��4�L^}=lI\OeNl<��:�,�NS�(�0{PK:�Y�DN~i.OXM��i?��I�p:�h�U&|�8E$1�����@B!0Ԉ�UP�dēC0����ʻL�]�i�`��Ǿ(   `�[�>��p��Uf�.����AN"�hZz���/��$AYh��!�/PR�Z���h�){
�NE�9>��)�b�@P��'"L�SD�Q��� kE�;�B�J(�c�q25�7�+���'�"�j�`IE�?����Oh(����i!C�y�O7���sO��;1�c9pث�L�J`'�δ�fЭ㔜�|����Iϵk�I�չ�a=;u(��V �#{�Dɸgr*���c���=�b���
[,��*�¦���F����L���~{Xe��   ;
H�3�9Ŕ���%��|��m�HAŒ�j}Ψe]�E��Q�͈������y�;{
(ߥ�E�a�[�M��i3��*
b��҇�D���i�ߞq��ii
f/P[SZ�6;�
_�A�e�X��mma-�C;�   �g-���;��#M�p5A"7�ʭ�U�6�ۓ���n̬�U���7�7 �e�20T��


˜�������K(aK�tf��"�(����eC�ū^�4����f�h+d�6H8��;Qj����K�vR[;��DL`�k^'���J
m!�ҠH�p��.Y�;ÕYK�<��=m[d���)�3�֊��gk���'���ǂl)�R���E�_�Ȼ�x�p�,NNnQ$�p��)�+�P-�5[;;��[�ut}�A�+ۀ5m�W,O�%����f>ĜV�m�A��� �x����u��*©�vD��Y�f5�ˋ�xW�ڳ'J�7�±6��3�t��'w�̮H$����Vn�ݓ�ѻb�M�S��3[v����'.�F�<�{�5͔�l.��Ī��Y �S�*ͧj�t�<P��"n� ���YN2r��ޮ��Ϟ���D��t�2�,Q�%���R���AdS����W=j��iMT��Pӎ$Z�^��b��6�d����b�l0�Z�p�����de1�����&��6���^b^����á�D��U�o�_���U�vléS��$tgy�0
]�oq���U�t�`�v=re2-:]�15���A��h��ͻi�o�uV4Ur��İwƬ8?4�獕iz��
Н����3&�D�@�@��"`����M$ �B�;L�IL�u�RS�%��`���D7۰�8G��ʔ��P94(�2�-��7F�е��(�(S`�� ������$1�"+����"E�(�͘>��J��g��=�Ѧ�9kj�Y���hAB�@����xi�����ͪ{��^�Z���V��T���m�
�@�9�?aN�\�v*@r�K�d$6i{�PL�>#ț}�z�ҀрCyO��lfiq^[F�:i?�V6��*  �L�P@K��h�VF�Ye���&�p�������b�>�RfU��N?�L?��fHH��^�0�7G��I�p`��"���x    ���6���f/hz�f&{���If���Tc3:s�6��P�d�@�H\D{Q��<��\��H����������<��?a{�� �����F�@��JIEND�B`�
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 constructor(public _DomSanitizationService: DomSanitizer) {}

 ...

 <img [src]="_DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:image/png;base64,' + response)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need createObjectURL from response

```
const blob = URL.createObjectURL(response);

const fileData  = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(blob);
```

If response base64 format

```
 const blob = 'data:image/png;base64,' + response;
  const fileData  = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(blob );
```

Comment: Cant create the blob variable in this way. It says: ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Comment: can you post the response data in your question?

Answer (score -1):

I only tested this with video, but it should work with images

```
     <input type="file" name="file" class="file"id="files"onchange="changefile()"/>

<video style="display: none;" id="vid"src="" width="350px" controls />
```

```
    document.querySelector("input[type=file]")
.onchange = function(event) {
  let file = event.target.files[0];
  let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  document.querySelector("img").style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector("img").src = blobURL;

}
```